# why the sub-navigation is hidden behind the slider advertisement lay under IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

when your mouse hover on the ACCESSORIES, the sub-navigation hide behind the slider advertisement  lay under IE, i have set the  slider lay, `z-index:99`;  the sub-navigation `z-index:9999`;but it doesn't work.
[image]

but ok under FF and chrome. how to correct it when under IE. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to community, you are facing this problem in IE7.

IE8, FF and chrome are giving perfect output. What you need to have is make your `.main-container z-index:-10 or -100` or so on.. try any values.

Set your z-index of `.nav-container` and `#nav` in positive values like `z-index:999` or 9999. try the value and check it simultaneously in all browser so you can identify where your css rules are affecting. For testing purpose you can set `border:1px solid red;` on any class or id. By using this you can see the boundaries of the element.

Check your position also some time IE treat positions differently. It not necessary that you are trying the z-index on ul or on ul ul work accordingly. Some time we have think about element's parent container also. If your layout or alignment will give problem in other browsers also you can use conditional statements and write specific css for particular browser.

See: [Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Comment: i add .main-container z-index:-10; to the style. but under IE7 it is still hidden behind the slider lay